# Error with MySql Query it shows part of the data and not the rest

Tags: php, mysql

In this index page of mine I have an error coming up with the code so I printed off the Query to see if the error is there and strangely enough I get the ID and Password of the query but not the username.

This is the print out:
`SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='3' AND username='' AND password='alan' LIMIT 1You data dont exist in the database`

where username field is empty should be Alan

here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
header("location: admin_login.php");
exit();
}

$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["username"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);

include"db_connection.php"; 
$q = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND  password='$password' LIMIT 1";
$sql = mysql_query($q);

echo $q;

$existCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($existCount ==0){
//header ("location: index.php");
echo "You data dont exist in the database";
exit();
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you using this from a form? If so, check if the input for it is properly named. This code seems to check out, so it's hard to say without knowing more. Your `3` and `alan` are coming from somewhere, how are they being entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following, I was able to successfully echo all three session variables.

Therefore, I am under the impression that either the `username` session variable is not set (from a previous form/HTML), and/or the form input element is not named or contains a typo.

Since you did not provide additional information in your (*original*) question in regards to how you are using it (from a form, or other) am submitting the following as a successful test.

I left out the first conditional statement from your code and filled in my own session variables.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION["id"] = "3";
$_SESSION["username"] = "FRED";
$_SESSION["password"] = "12345";

$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["username"]);
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);

echo $_SESSION["id"];
echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION["username"];
echo "<br>";
echo $_SESSION["password"];
```

Which echo'ed:

3
FRED
12345

I am questioning this line though, since there is no other reference to it:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"]))
```

since it seems to be related to the word "manager"

```
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
```

where you might have meant to use:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["id"]))
```

or:

```
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["manager"]);
```